# How to take two different data type user input in one line?

Tags: kotlin, split, user-input

```
var (a,b)= readLine()!!.split(" ").map { it.toInt() }
```

it's about to take one kind of data type in one line.
But how can I take two different data type, same as above? like- "integer" space "float"
I have to take user input- integer a and float b in one line with a space.
// 1 2.0

```
fun main(){
    //var (a,b)= readLine()!!.split(" ").map { it.toInt() }
    var a = readLine()!!.toInt()
    var b= readLine()!!.toFloat()
    if (a>b){
        var roundNumber= "%.2f".format(b)
        println(roundNumber)
    }
    else if (a%5==0 && b>=a+0.5){
        var c= b-(a+0.5)
        var roundNumber= "%.2f".format(c)
        println(roundNumber)
    }
    else{
        var roundNum= "%.2f".format(b)
        println(roundNum)
    }
}
```

Input:
30
120.00
Output:
89.50 (It's Working)
....
But the fact is I have to put input two in one line with a space.
Input:
30 120.00

Comment: Not sure if i understand you correctly but If you want to see output in one line just use `print` instead of `println`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to map both string representations of an integer and a floating point number using `toInt()` which will return null for the floating point input which is not what you want.

One solution would be to split the line into a list of strings and then convert them separately

```kotlin
val components = readLine()!!.split(" ")
val a = components[0].toInt()
val b = components[1].toFloat()
```

Another option is to use a Java scanner

First import the scanner at the top of your file.

```
import java.util.Scanner
```

Then create a scanner object and use it to extract the values from the input line.

```kotlin
  val scanner = Scanner(readLine())
  val a = scanner.nextInt()
  val b = scanner.nextFloat()
```

Answer (score 0):

I gues you need to use try-catch statement to individually map each input into a list, then have whichever casted into the the desired type, if not invalid input (of course).

```kotlin
fun main() {

    val cordTTT = readln().split(' ').map {
        try {
            it.toFloat()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            "not applicable"
        }
    }

    cordTTT.forEach(::println)

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).